# Insufficient RAM for Intel XEON E5-2699 v4

Tags: cpu, performance, xeon

I just finished building my first workstation. Here is the configuration I have:

Motherboard: Supermico X10DAX (just 1 CPU installed)

CPU: Intel XEON E5-2699 v4 (ES version)

GPU: nVidia QUADRO K1200

RAM: Crucial 288 Pin 32 GB (16 GB x2) CL15 DDR4 DIMM Memory Module (ecc registered)

Storage: Crucial MX300 525 GB SATA 2.5 Inch Internal Solid State Drive with 9.5 mm Adapter AND WD Red 4 TB NAS Desktop Hard Disk Drive - Intellipower SATA 6 Gb/s 64MB Cache 3.5 Inch

Though the system is quite high-end, I am totally unhappy with the overall performance. Quite honestly, my other workstation, a Dell Precision M3800, is performing way better. And here's the configuration as well, so you can compare them:

CPU: Intel i7 -4702HQ @ 2.20GHz

RAM: 16GB

GPU: nVidia Quadro K1100M

The issues I'm experiencing with the homebuilt workstation include lag, sluggish performance, and occasional freezing. This happens especially with Adobe Photoshop CC 2017 (most recent version). The overall response is very slow after about 15 minutes. It becomes unusable.

I have come across this thread (https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/hardware/144936-singl...). The OP seems to be experiencing something quite similar. Now, one of the users has raised an interesting point about having created a memory bottleneck. I have just one processor and 2 RAM modules (16 GB each, so 32GB total). After reading the thread I realized I hadn't installed the RAM modules properly. My motherboard has 8 modules/CPU and dual CPU capability. The 8 modules are distributed evenly on each side of the processor (4 on the left side and 4 on the right side). When I installed the RAM, I place one module on one side and the other module on the other side. I eventually moved one module to enable the dual-channel memory architecture. I placed them in slots 2 & 4, which I think is the correct way.

The performance is still quite poor as compared to what I was expecting. I also came across maximum memory bandwidth, and I'm confused if I should necessarily try to compute/achieve the CPU's maximum memory bandwidth of 76.8GB/s. Will this make a difference in how the system performs? As I have only 32GB of RAM installed, this essentially lowers the memory bandwidth to about half, so maybe the performance is also about a half. Should I add another 2 x 16GB RAM modules? I know each core needs to be allocated a minimum of 2000MB.

Reading the same thread, one of the users says it's important to populate "bank 1 of all 4 channels for each CPU". What exactly does this mean? What is bank 1? I know a channel is, for example, A1, A2, and the other is B1, B2 (so I'd need to place a RAM module in the first slot of each channel, i.e. A1, B1, which I did). How many more RAM modules would I need to achieve optimum performance?

I did a few tests to stress the CPU and GPU. I used Furmark for about 30 minutes and all was fine. No artifacts whatsoever. Furmark hasn't crashed at all. I used Prime95 to stress the CPU for about 3 hours. No problem here either. For RAM, I ran Memtest86 for 10 hours. The results were 2 passed and no error. So no problem here either.

I also ran a SSD benchmark test. Here are the results I've got:

[image]

As you can see, the score is pretty low. I don't think the SSD is causing the issues I'm experiencing.

When I first experienced the lag, I thought it was keyboard/mouse-related. They were a no-name company (and fairly cheap as well), so I assumed this was the culprit. I purchased a Logitech MK520 Wireless Combo, and though it seemed to be working well at first, now I'm seemingly experiencing the same issues. Sometimes the cursor is moving quite slowly, and the keyboard takes some time to respond when I type something. As a side note, the problems are not software-specific. They occur when in Google Chrome, Adobe Photoshop CC 17, and pretty much every other program I run. The keyboard is particularly frustrating. The letters take a few seconds to show up.

Filters keys are off (it seems to be causing similar problems for other users, but not in my case). And since both keyboards and mice are behaving similarly, I doubt they're the culprit.

Interestingly, the performance is not always so bad. The first day I used the workstation, it was working very well. The next day, it was a nightmare. I was experiencing everything I described above. Then all was well the next two days. And now it's performing poorly again.

Another note: the performance is similar to when I'm stressing the CPU, but the CPU usage is maximum 3%.

As I said, this is the first workstation I've ever built, and I'm not experienced with hardware. So any input/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!